# Saving mat files in different numerical data formats in scipy.io.savemat

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I know this is very simple and I can't believe I haven't found anything on this anywhere but here it goes:

I have a large, high dimensional matrix in python that I want to save in .mat format (for matlab). 
I'm using the scipy.io.savemat method to save this matrix but it's always saved as double. I would like to save it as something of lower precision, like single or 16 bit float.

I convert the array to a low-precision data type before saving but it's always saved as double. Is there really no way of saving mat files in a lower-precision float type?

.savemat does not seem to take a dtype argument.

```
 import scipy as sp
 sp.io.savemat('test.mat', {'test': sp.array([0.001, 1, 1.004], dtype='Float16')})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it needs to be either single or double. scipy.io.savemat() does not support other float precisions and it'll casually default to double if it doesn't like your dtype without warning.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks for looking this up. Newer matlab versions also write to hdf5 type files if this is any help.

Comment: Yes, in my simple tests, 'float32' and 'float' produce different size files ('float' is 2x larger), but 'float16' saves like 'float'.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf - that  single and double float business is a MATLAB constraint.  On the other hand for ints, 'int16' and 'int8' work.

Comment: @hpaulj, That's true, it's Matlab's design. I guess what's sort of counter intuitive is that it uses float64 when float16 is not available, instead of 32. The fact that it's not documented in scipy and it doesn't display any warning is also somewhat bothersome.

Comment: In `numpy`, `float64` is the default float value. There probably isn't much code in `savemat` devoted to handing this issue.

Comment: What should I do to force savemat() to save in single precision and not as double