# Why does saving mat files with scipy result in larger file size than with Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, save

Let's say I generate the following toy dataset from Matlab, and I save it as a mat file:

```
>> arr = rand(100);
>> whos arr
  Name        Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

  arr       100x100            80000  double
>> save('arr.mat', 'arr')
```

The saved `arr.mat` file is of size `75829 Bytes` according to the output of the `ls` command.

If I load the same file using `scipy.io.loadmat()` and save it again using `scipy.io.savemat()`:

```
arr = io.loadmat('arr.mat')
with open('arrscipy.mat', 'w') as f:
    io.savemat(f, arr)
```

I obtain a file with a considerably different size (∼ 4KB larger):

```
$ ls -al
75829 Nov  6 11:52 arr.mat
80184 Nov  6 11:52 arrscipy.mat
```

I now have two binary mat files containing the same data. My understanding is that the size of a binary mat file is determined by the size of its contained variables, plus some overhead due to file headers. However **the sizes of these two files are considerably different**. Why is this? [Is it a data format problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326266/saving-mat-files-in-different-numerical-data-formats-in-scipy-io-savemat)

I tried this with arrays of structures too, and the result is similar: scipy-saved mat files are larger than Matlab-saved ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html):

```
scipy.io.savemat(file_name, mdict, appendmat=True, format='5',
    long_field_names=False, do_compression=False, oned_as='row')
```

Compression is turned off by default. In matlab compression is always turned on.

Comment: Even better. Now the scipy-saved mat file is smaller than the matlab-saved one: `75602 Bytes` for scipy with `do_compression=True` against `75829 Bytes` for Matlab `save('arr.mat', 'arr')`. Do you have an answer as to how this might happen?

Answer (score 3):

There's a catch when you set do_compression=True. For large files, MATLAB cannot load when saved with do_compression=True.

In my case, mat files under 2 GB didn't have any problem loading from my MATLAB (2017b) whether do_compression is True or False, but when I load 2.25 GB mat file saved using scipy.io.savemat() with compression, MATLAB failed to load even though I can load it from Python using loadmat().

In scipy.io.savemat manual, the default value of format = '5', which supports up to MATLAB 7.2. It is the latest version it supports. In MATLAB's save() documentation, however, it says it needs to be saved with '-v7.3' for files over 2GB. I think the reason scipy's savemat fails to save correctly is because it doesn't support MATLAB 7.3 version for mat files larger than 2GB.

Hopefully scipy will have an upgrade to fix this problem.

Comment: MAT5 files use integers for the length headers, so there is a fundamental limit of 2GB per root-level variable. It shouldn't matter whether the data gets compressed or not. It sounds like a bug if SciPy isn't complaining when you try to store a variable larger than 2GB. The "new" MATLAB 7.3 format is a completely different format that is "based" on HDF5 and has nothing to do with the MAT5 version. It's unfortunately not a simple upgrade, but would require a completely different implementation of an as far as I know undocumented format.

Comment: good to know for this repo: https://github.com/yu4u/age-gender-estimation