# matlab with float data results in strangely large size

Tags: python, matlab

I have a text file consisting of 4096 float numbers every line, with 123287 lines total, and I'm converting it to a .mat file.

Looking at other files of the same amount of data, and my calculation yield that resulting mat file should be less than 1GB, whereas resulting mat file with the following code resulted in 3.8 GB. What could've gone wrong?

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
add = np.zeros(shape=(4096,123287))

i=0
for l in open('data.txt','r'):
    l=l.split()
    j=0
    for e in l:
        try:
            add[j][i]=np.float32(e)
            j+=1
        except IndexError:
            continue
    i+=1
scipy.io.savemat('data.mat',{'feats':add})
```

Comment: Note that `add` is a matrix of doubles. You have not specified data type. Adding data of type float32 will not change the data type of `add` but the float32 variables will implicitly convert to float64, Further, I am not very good in python, but general programming instinct says that you read data as a char array. Are you sure you really have 4096 numbers and not 4096 digits? Have you tried to look at your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default type in matlab for working with non integers is double, which occupies 8 bytes.

in your array you have 504983552 elements (4096*123287 = 504983552).

in bytes: 504983552*8 = 4039868416, which is 4039.86 mb.

if you convert the data type to single instead of double, you can cut this value by half.

Comment: How do I set the default type as single on python?

Comment: take a look on the following thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326266/saving-mat-files-in-different-numerical-data-formats-in-scipy-io-savemat

Comment: I have a downloaded mat file which has the same number of elements, with each element being numpy float32 type, and it is 700Mb. What could have reduced the size in this case?

Comment: Note that `single` of course has half the precision that `double` has. So you basically trade storage space for accuracy.

Comment: for your second question: when saving a mat file, there's a process of compression which may be influenced by the complexity of the matrix elements. for example, a matrix which contains long sequences of the same value will probably be saved in a more compact file. Also, a sparse matrix which contains a lot of zeros will be compressed more efficiently.